# Get Column Name of CSV file

Tags: r

I want to get column Names of CSV data and apply some functions on column name.

I tried the following code, but the output just returns data type

```
reading_data <- read.csv("test.csv")

print("Header Row:")
print(reading_data[0,])  # This gives me a list of column names correctly
print(class(reading_data[0,])) # O/P is: "data.frame"
print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
for(i in 1:ncol(reading_data)){ 
    print(reading_data[0,i]) # O/P is: numeric(0) ; I want string value of data name here.
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. If you are already loading your data then why don't you just do `names(reading_data)`...?

Comment: I want to apply some functions on column Names, so need individual string name of each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reading_data[0,]` doesn't return you the column names, it returns you a dataframe with no rows selected.

Check for example with `mtcars`

```
mtcars[1, ]
#          mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

This is 1st row of `mtcars` with column names.

Now if you do `mtcars[0, ]`

```
mtcars[0, ]
# [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It returns column names as it is with no rows selected as there is no row at index 0.

If you want to apply some functions on each column name separately you can do

```
for(i in names(reading_data)){ 
    print(i) 
    #add the operation to be applied here
}
```

`names(mtcars)` or `colnames(mtcars)` would give you the column names directly.

```
names(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
colnames(mtcars)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to get column names is not `reading_data[0,]` but rather use the `colnames()` function... in this case, `colnames(reading_data)`.

If you want these stored in a vector use

```
colnames_df <- colnames(reading_data)
```

Which you could apply your function to (you can also apply it directly to `colnames(reading_data)`).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers.

**names(reading_data)** served my purpose.

```
col_names = names(reading_data)

for(i in 1:length(col_names)){ 
  print(col_names[i]) 
  # Operation on col_names[i]
}
```

PS: I am a newbie in R, so do not know all these basic functions :)